# HTML - <link href=*> sending HTTP request?

Tags: html, hyperlink, resources, href

I was wondering if the HTML code below make the browser to send an HTTP request to get the resource ?

```
<link href="https://developer.cdn.mozilla.net/static/build/styles/mdn.593f20d8c365.css">
```

In fact, I tried to check with a local proxy, but my browser did not send an HTTP request to get it ....

Comment: you'd need to tell the browxser that the link is indeed css. not all links require an external access the moment the `<link>` is encountered.

Answer (score 1):

You're missing the `rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"`.  On top of that, not all servers will allow a remote link to a CSS file.  So it might not work either way.